# How to find the dimension of this field extension?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

> Let $p(x)=x^3-x+1$ in $\mathbb{Q[x]}$ and $\alpha$ algebraic in $\mathbb{Q}$, such that $p(\alpha)=0$. If $\beta = 1+\alpha-2\alpha^2 \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. It's true that $[\mathbb{Q}(\beta): \mathbb{Q}]=3$?

I've tried see if $p(\beta)=0$, but it is not true.

I did not find a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q[x]}$ such that $\beta$ is a root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *real* question here is if

$p(x) = x^3 - x + 1 \in \Bbb Q[x] \tag 1$

is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$?  This may in fact be obvious to some; nevertheless I proffer the following simple demonstration, largely an exercise in elementary number theory:

If $p(x)$ *were* reducible, being a monic cubic polynomial it would have a linear factor $x - \rho$ over $\Bbb Q$, hence $\rho \in \Bbb Q$ would be a root of $p(x)$:

$p(\rho) = 0; \tag 2$

we set

$\rho = \dfrac{r}{s}, \; r, s \in \Bbb Z, \; s \ge 1, \tag 3$

with

$\gcd(r, s) = 1; \tag 4$

then (1), (2) and (3) together yield

$\dfrac{r^3}{s^3} - \dfrac{r}{s}+ 1 = 0, \tag 5$

which in turn yields

$r^3 = s^2r - s^3 \Longrightarrow s \mid r^3; \tag 6$

thus for any prime $q$ dividing $s$,

$q \mid s \Longrightarrow q \mid r^3 \Longrightarrow q \mid r \Rightarrow \Leftarrow \gcd(r, s) = 1; \tag 7$

this shows there is in fact *no* prime $q \mid s$, hence

$s = 1; \tag 8$

therefore,

$(r - 1)r(r + 1) = r^3 - r = -1; \tag 9$

which is impossible since $-1$ cannot be the product of three consecutive integers, as is easy to see; that $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ has thus been proved.

Since $p(x) \in \Bbb Q[x]$ is irreducible, it follows then that

$[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q] = 3; \tag{10}$

this allows us to write

$[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q(\beta)] [\Bbb Q(\beta):\Bbb Q] = [\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q] = 3, \tag{11}$

which in turn implies that

$[\Bbb Q(\beta):\Bbb Q] = 1 \; \text{or} \; 3; \tag{12}$

but

$[\Bbb Q(\beta):\Bbb Q] = 1 \Longrightarrow \beta \in \Bbb Q \Longrightarrow 2x^2 - x  + \beta - 1 \in \Bbb Q[x],  \tag{13}$

and since

$\beta = -2\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1, \tag{14}$

or

$2\alpha^2 - \alpha + \beta - 1 = 0, \tag{15}$

we find

$[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q] \le 2\Rightarrow \Leftarrow [\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q] = 3; \tag{16}$

we conclude therefore that

$[\Bbb Q(\beta):\Bbb Q] = 3. \tag{14}$

Comment: Sir upto (15) I understood each and every step. But after that I didn't understand "how" we get (16) and I didn't understand meanings of symbols (implies...) used in (16) too. Please elaborate...

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi:  the symbol $\Rightarrow \Leftarrow$ is shorthand for "contradicts"; so (16) simply says that $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q] \le 2$ contradicts what we already know, that $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q] = 3$.  Is  that clear?

Comment: Ok sir got it, we had obtained contradiction to the fact $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]$ is $3$. Hence our assumption that $[\mathbb{Q}(\beta):\mathbb{Q}]$ is $1$ is wrong. Hence $[\mathbb{Q}(\beta):\mathbb{Q}]=3$. But still "I didn't get" "how in (16) you get, $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha): \mathbb{Q}]≤2$ "

Comment: Sir please reply, how we get $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]≤2$

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi:  it comes from (13)-(15) where we show that, when $\beta \in \Bbb Q$, $\alpha$ obeys a *quadratic* in $\Bbb Q[x]$.

Comment: Sir, extremely sorry to trouble you. I am beginner in "advanced linear algebra and field theory". Sir, are you using any result or theorem? Because I still didn't get that, if $\alpha$ obeys quadratic polynomial in $Q[x]$ then why $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]≤2$ ?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi:  do you know what $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q]$ means, how it is defibed?

Comment: Yes sir. Here $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha): \mathbb{Q}]$ is an extension field of $\mathbb{Q}$. In particular, it is smallest extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\alpha$ both, where $\alpha$ is root of $p(x)$.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi:  not quite, $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ is the extension, but $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q]$ is the *dimension* of $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ as a *vector space* over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Sorry sir, for my mistake in last comment. Yes it is dimension of extension field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ considered as vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. But why its dimension ≤2?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi:  because it satisfies the polynomial (15) which says that $1, \alpha, \alpha^2$ are linearly dependent over $\Bbb Q$

Comment: Oh thank you so much sir. This is what hidden through my eyes. Thank you so much sir for this wonderful explanation and for the above beautiful answer.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi:  thanks for the kind wordsd my friend!